# Assign the return value of two functions, to two variables, in a do block

Tags: haskell

Sorry for the title gore (if you can suggest a better, please do). But my problem is that I dont quite understand how to get this do block to work. I have a code that returns the position of `5` in a list of lists. Like such:

```
findFive :: [[Int]] -> (Int, Int)
findFive rs = do
    x <- xPos rs 0
    y <- yPos rs 0
    return ( (x,y) )

xPos :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int
xPos (rs:[[]]) n             = n
xPos (rs:rss)  n | elem 5 rs = n
                 | otherwise = xPos rss (n+1)

yPos :: [[Int]] -> Int -> Int
yPos (rs:[[]]) n              = n
yPos (rs:rss)  n | elem 5 rs  = n
                 | otherwise  = yPos rss (n+1)
```

I

But I cant use my do block this way. I can get it to work by doing

```
findFive :: [[Int]] -> (Int, Int)
findFive xs = ( (xPos xs 0), (yPos (transpose (xs)) 0) )
```

But that looks kinda ugly.

Also, is there a way to get this to work without sending in `0` to `xPos` and `yPos` ?

Comment: xPos and yPos are identical except the name. This is completely unnecessary and avoids the whole point of functions. When you find yourself coding with copy and paste, there is almost always a better way.

Comment: @Code-Apprentice Yeah. I noticed it to, Change it to one `pos` function instead. And calls transpose on the list I send in for the Y position

Comment: One small comment... in `(yPos (transpose (xs))` you don't need the parentheses around `xs`. Remember that in Haskell, function application is a simple space. Parentheses are used for specifying operator precedence. This is unlike the use of parentheses in other languages when calling a function. You may already know this. I just wanted to point it out for future readers.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why `do`? There are no monads there. A `let..in` suffices:

```
findFive :: [[Int]] -> (Int, Int)
findFive rs = let
    x = xPos rs 0
    y = yPos rs 0
    in (x,y)
```

Alternatively, use `where`:

```
findFive :: [[Int]] -> (Int, Int)
findFive rs = (x, y)
    where
    x = xPos rs 0
    y = yPos rs 0
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use a `do` block this way because in `do` blocks you have to (1) bind names to the 'contents' of monadic values, and (2) return a value wrapped in the same monadic type as used in (1). In this case the monadic type would be the list. It's appropriate to return a list of (row, column) pairs because that automatically handles both the cases of not finding the number, or finding it multiple times. So we could do something like

```
import Control.Monad

findFive ::
  [[Int]] ->   -- ^ a matrix of numbers.
  [(Int, Int)] -- ^ the (zero-indexed) rows and columns of the number
               -- ^ @5@, if any (otherwise empty list).
findFive xss =
  do
    (xs, rowIdx) <- xss `zip` [0 ..]
    (x, colIdx) <- xs `zip` [0 ..]
    guard $ x == 5

    return (rowIdx, colIdx)

input :: [[Int]]
input = [[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]]

-- Should print "row: 1, col: 1".
main :: IO ()
main =
  forM_ (findFive input) $ \(rowIdx, colIdx) ->
    do
      putStr "row: "
      putStr $ show rowIdx
      putStr ", col: "
      print colIdx
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's say `pos` is defined this way:

```
pos :: Eq =>    a          -- A value to find
             -> [[a]]      -- A 2d matrix
             -> Maybe Int  -- Index of first row containing the value, if any
pos k rows = pos' rows 0
             where pos' [] _ = Nothing
                   pos' (x:xs) n | elem k x = n
                                 | otherwise = pos' xs (n+1)
```

There are several changes here:

1. It will work for lists of any type on which equality is defined, not just `Int`.
2. It is generalized to find any value `k :: a`, not just 5.
3. It can deal with failure to find *any* row containing `k`.

With this definition, we could define `findFive` as

```
findFive :: [[Int]] -> (Maybe Int, Maybe Int)
findFive xs = (pos 5 xs, pos 5 (transpose xs))
```

---

Using `Control.Lens`, you can factor out the function `pos 5` so that it only needs to be written once. Think of `over both` as a version of `map` for pairs instead of lists.

```
import Control.Lens
findFive xs = over both (pos 5) (xs, transpose xs)
```

Using `Control.Arrow`, you can factor out the argument `xs` so that *it* only needs to be written once.

```
import Control.Lens
import Control.Arrow
findFive xs = over both (pos 5) ((id &&& transpose) xs)
-- id &&& transpose = \x -> (id x, transpose x)
```

Once you've done that, you can easily write `findFive` in point-free style, by composing `over both (pos 5)` and `id &&& transpose`:

```
findFive = over both (pos 5) . (id &&& transpose)
```